# Way to change the default doctype to XHTML strict for newly-created ASP.NET MVC views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Besides copy/paste on each newly-added View, that is...

And can anyone think of any reasons not to use Strict doctype with ASP.NET MVC 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but I recommend that you copy / paste the CodeTemplates into your solution and then edit the .tt files with your preferred DocType. This will save you time and work. Assuming you are using CSharp the CodeTemplates are found in /Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/ItemTemplates/CSharp/Web/MVC 2/CodeTemplates

Answer (score 1):

Use a masterpage.

The reason why websites use the Transitional doctype is because they want to use

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="external-link">Go to Google</a>
```

so that it opens in a new window/tab or use a Rich Text Editor that uses an IFrame.